# Where can I get the Emulator as a stand alone application?

Tags: windows-mobile, emulation

I need to install the Emulator (for Windows Mobile 6.5) as a stand alone application.

I usually just get it with Visual Studio, but I need to install it on a non-developer machine.

Any ideas where I can find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DD567053-F231-4A64-A648-FEA5E7061303

PS  This may also be helpful: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e

This is a version for VS 2008: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=a6f6adaf-12e3-4b2f-a394-356e2c2fb114&displaylang=en